# WooCommerce registration password field not displaying

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, forms

For WooCommerce registration form we only have one email field and I want to add password fields for this. I have tried to find online help but there are few support pages only for repeat password field.
On the other hand I need the first default password field and the repeat password field as well.
How I can create these. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable default Password field I just had to check checkbox (When creating an account, automatically generate an account password) under WooComemrce > Settings > Accounts and Privacy.

After this default password field started to display on registration page. To add repeat password field I used this hook

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'wc_register_form_password_repeat' );
function wc_register_form_password_repeat() {
?>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
<label for="reg_password2"><?php _e( 'Password Repeat', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password2" id="reg_password2" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['password2'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['password2'] ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php
}
?>
```